# Illegal String offset capabilities

Tags: wordpress

I continue to get this error when trying to login to the Wordpress admin area:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'capabilities' in
> /home/content/p3pnexwpnas16_data03/95/3712595/html/wp-includes/class-wp-roles.php
> on line 127
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in
> /home/content/p3pnexwpnas16_data03/95/3712595/html/wp-includes/class-wp-roles.php
> on line 128

I was almost done with this extensive site: http://lihouston.org

Your help is GREATLY appreciated. I have a splash page setup that displays if your not logged in. I am at a total loss of what to do or what is wrong. I have been unable to login to FTP as well. Everything was working fine and then this....

Comment: Illegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key

Comment: which version of wordpress are you using?

Comment: If you have a host access then change version PHP version to 5.3.I  think your theme not support 5.3 > version.Once you done error might be removed.

Comment: This isn't on my server, so I'm trying to obtain host access now. Right now I only have access to FTP. It finally let me in. I didn't update anything recently. Is there a way to update through FTP?

Comment: I have  database access now too. Wordpress version 4.70

Comment: PHP 45.40.164.113 - Server version: 5.6.32-78.0-log

Comment: Will Godaddy allow me to change the PHP version? Ive never done that before.

Comment: Here is the error log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5nAqL614cUuNjlSMEtnTHZySTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Its simple thing.:)

Comment: Your theme is outdated.

Comment: send me theme on vasimmca007 at gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The problem happened with me when the value of `wp_user_roles` option had been corrupted for some reason. I solved it by copying the value of this option from the staging site.

The SQL query looked like this for me:

`insert into wp_options set option_name = 'wp_user_roles', option_value='a:7:{s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Administrator";s:12:"capabilities";a:114:{s:13:"switch_themes";b:1;s:11:"edit_themes";b:1;s:16:"activate_plugins";b:1;s:12:"edit_plugins";b:1;s:10:"edit_users";b:1;s:10:"edit_files";b:1;s:14:"manage_options";b:1;s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:6:"import";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:8:"level_10";b:1;s:7:"level_9";b:1;s:7:"level_8";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_users";b:1;s:12:"create_users";b:1;s:17:"unfiltered_upload";b:1;s:14:"edit_dashboard";b:1;s:14:"update_plugins";b:1;s:14:"delete_plugins";b:1;s:15:"install_plugins";b:1;s:13:"update_themes";b:1;s:14:"install_themes";b:1;s:11:"update_core";b:1;s:10:"list_users";b:1;s:12:"remove_users";b:1;s:13:"promote_users";b:1;s:18:"edit_theme_options";b:1;s:13:"delete_themes";b:1;s:6:"export";b:1;s:18:"manage_woocommerce";b:1;s:24:"view_woocommerce_reports";b:1;s:12:"edit_product";b:1;s:12:"read_product";b:1;s:14:"delete_product";b:1;s:13:"edit_products";b:1;s:20:"edit_others_products";b:1;s:16:"publish_products";b:1;s:21:"read_private_products";b:1;s:15:"delete_products";b:1;s:23:"delete_private_products";b:1;s:25:"delete_published_products";b:1;s:22:"delete_others_products";b:1;s:21:"edit_private_products";b:1;s:23:"edit_published_products";b:1;s:20:"manage_product_terms";b:1;s:18:"edit_product_terms";b:1;s:20:"delete_product_terms";b:1;s:20:"assign_product_terms";b:1;s:15:"edit_shop_order";b:1;s:15:"read_shop_order";b:1;s:17:"delete_shop_order";b:1;s:16:"edit_shop_orders";b:1;s:23:"edit_others_shop_orders";b:1;s:19:"publish_shop_orders";b:1;s:24:"read_private_shop_orders";b:1;s:18:"delete_shop_orders";b:1;s:26:"delete_private_shop_orders";b:1;s:28:"delete_published_shop_orders";b:1;s:25:"delete_others_shop_orders";b:1;s:24:"edit_private_shop_orders";b:1;s:26:"edit_published_shop_orders";b:1;s:23:"manage_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:21:"edit_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:23:"delete_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:23:"assign_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:16:"edit_shop_coupon";b:1;s:16:"read_shop_coupon";b:1;s:18:"delete_shop_coupon";b:1;s:17:"edit_shop_coupons";b:1;s:24:"edit_others_shop_coupons";b:1;s:20:"publish_shop_coupons";b:1;s:25:"read_private_shop_coupons";b:1;s:19:"delete_shop_coupons";b:1;s:27:"delete_private_shop_coupons";b:1;s:29:"delete_published_shop_coupons";b:1;s:26:"delete_others_shop_coupons";b:1;s:25:"edit_private_shop_coupons";b:1;s:27:"edit_published_shop_coupons";b:1;s:24:"manage_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;s:22:"edit_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;s:24:"delete_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;s:24:"assign_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;}}s:6:"editor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Editor";s:12:"capabilities";a:34:{s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;}}s:6:"author";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Author";s:12:"capabilities";a:10:{s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;}}s:11:"contributor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:11:"Contributor";s:12:"capabilities";a:5:{s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;}}s:10:"subscriber";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Subscriber";s:12:"capabilities";a:2:{s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;}}s:8:"customer";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:8:"Customer";s:12:"capabilities";a:1:{s:4:"read";b:1;}}s:12:"shop_manager";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:12:"Shop manager";s:12:"capabilities";a:92:{s:7:"level_9";b:1;s:7:"level_8";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:6:"export";b:1;s:6:"import";b:1;s:10:"list_users";b:1;s:18:"edit_theme_options";b:1;s:18:"manage_woocommerce";b:1;s:24:"view_woocommerce_reports";b:1;s:12:"edit_product";b:1;s:12:"read_product";b:1;s:14:"delete_product";b:1;s:13:"edit_products";b:1;s:20:"edit_others_products";b:1;s:16:"publish_products";b:1;s:21:"read_private_products";b:1;s:15:"delete_products";b:1;s:23:"delete_private_products";b:1;s:25:"delete_published_products";b:1;s:22:"delete_others_products";b:1;s:21:"edit_private_products";b:1;s:23:"edit_published_products";b:1;s:20:"manage_product_terms";b:1;s:18:"edit_product_terms";b:1;s:20:"delete_product_terms";b:1;s:20:"assign_product_terms";b:1;s:15:"edit_shop_order";b:1;s:15:"read_shop_order";b:1;s:17:"delete_shop_order";b:1;s:16:"edit_shop_orders";b:1;s:23:"edit_others_shop_orders";b:1;s:19:"publish_shop_orders";b:1;s:24:"read_private_shop_orders";b:1;s:18:"delete_shop_orders";b:1;s:26:"delete_private_shop_orders";b:1;s:28:"delete_published_shop_orders";b:1;s:25:"delete_others_shop_orders";b:1;s:24:"edit_private_shop_orders";b:1;s:26:"edit_published_shop_orders";b:1;s:23:"manage_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:21:"edit_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:23:"delete_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:23:"assign_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:16:"edit_shop_coupon";b:1;s:16:"read_shop_coupon";b:1;s:18:"delete_shop_coupon";b:1;s:17:"edit_shop_coupons";b:1;s:24:"edit_others_shop_coupons";b:1;s:20:"publish_shop_coupons";b:1;s:25:"read_private_shop_coupons";b:1;s:19:"delete_shop_coupons";b:1;s:27:"delete_private_shop_coupons";b:1;s:29:"delete_published_shop_coupons";b:1;s:26:"delete_others_shop_coupons";b:1;s:25:"edit_private_shop_coupons";b:1;s:27:"edit_published_shop_coupons";b:1;s:24:"manage_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;s:22:"edit_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;s:24:"delete_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;s:24:"assign_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;}}}'`